# conflicting og:type found in path (object) and 'properties'

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

Facebook share dialogue.
Platform: iOS, Android.

2-3 weeks ago it all worked fine, but today I can't show a share dialogue properly. The error occurs: `conflicting og:type found in path (object) and 'properties' (games.victory)`

https://monosnap.com/file/XTbGqcbIKaQOGxb93G2LiDmdI1Qu3g
conflicting og:type found in path (object) and 'properties' (games.victory)
What changed? How to fix this?

Here's an example for iOS:

```
NSDictionary * properties =
@{
  @"fb:app_id" : @"123456789",
  @"og:type" : @"games.victory",
  @"og:title" : @"Some title",
  @"og:description" : @"A message",
  @"og:url" : @"http://link.to.app.com",
  @"og:image" : @"https://link.to.image.png"
  };

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
    [action setObject:object forKey:@"victory"];
    action.actionType = @"games.celebrate";

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
    content.action = action;
    content.previewPropertyName = @"victory";

    FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];

    shareDialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb;
    shareDialog.delegate=self;
    shareDialog.fromViewController = UnityGetGLViewController();
    shareDialog.shareContent = content;
    [shareDialog show];
```

Comment: you should provide og tags in the shared url, not in your code. share dialogs take the og tags from the url automatically.

Comment: I did as it described in the tutorial [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios), at the bottom of the page. And the example from the tutorial works. I can't figure out why my example doesn't.